# Avoid update data outside of repository

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to know what's the correct way of updating a data inside a service layer or repository and avoid to make changes to the object outside service/repository.. example:

```
public class PersonRepository{
     public class Insert(Person person){
          //code
          _db.SaveChanges();
     }
}

public class TaskRepository{
     public class Insert(Task task){
          //code
          _db.SaveChanges();
     }

     public void Update(Task task){}
}
```

and an example code in controller:

```
public ActionResult Insert(Task task)
{
     _taskRepository.Insert(task);

     task.Title = "foo";

     _personRepository.Insert(new Person()); //here the problem!
}
```

when I save a new person automatically entity will update the title of task!!!
So how can I control it? I want deny insert/update outside the main repository(in this case, task MUST the inserted/updated only inside the taskRepository).

Should I disable proxy? or change tracking? or else?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the repositories are sharing a a DBContext. Therefore calling  `_db.SaveChanges();` in the PersonRepository will cause the DBContext object to save all changes made to entities it is tracking - this includes the task object.

There are various ways to avoid this, but wrapping the DBContext object in a `using` statement will ensure it is disposed after it performs its job and will not be tracking the objects it has returned.

```
public class TaskRepository
{
     public class Insert(Task task)
     {
          using(var db = new YourContext())
          {
              //code here
              db.SaveChanges();
          }
     } 
}
```

Note that this can have performance implications as creating and destroying DBContexts can be expensive.

Comment: thank, I thought it, but in my project I would like to use unit of work, so I can't do this. +1 anyway.

Comment: I see. have you thought about call the DbContext Detach() method after SaveChanges, this would stop EF tracking the entity after it has been saved.

Comment: Yes :) but is a bit boring isn't?